# Python, FileNotFoundError, cuando sí existe el archivo en la misma ruta

Tags: python

Para realizar un código de python (pasar un archivo de texto a voz), necesito extraer información de un fichero en concreto que se encuentra en el mismo directorio.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyttsx3

class Voz(object):


def __init__(self):

    self.__engine = pyttsx3.init()
    #segundo valor, voz compatible con mi ordenador
    self.__engine.setProperty('voice','spanish')

def leerTexto(self, fichero):

    fichero = "texto.txt"
    engine = pyttsx3.init()

    #try:
    f = open(fichero, "r")
    l = f.readline()
        
    engine.say(l)
    engine.runAndWait()


    #except FileNotFoundError:
        #error= "Error de lectura. No puedo leer el fichero"
        #engine.say(error)
        #engine.runAndWait() 



lector = Voz()
lector.leerTexto("fichero")
```

Aún comprobando el nombre del fichero, la dirección de ruta de ambos archivos para que coincidiera, cambiando de directorio todo el proyecto... Persiste el siguiente error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'texto.txt'

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo.

---

Adición, para más información:

Directorio del trabajo de la consola

```
import os 
print(os.getcwd())
>>PS C:\Users\hp> & "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" "c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Nueva carpeta (2)/programa.py"
```

C:\Users\hp

Directorio del proyecto
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (2)

Comment: El archivo que quieres abrir se llama de casualidad fichero.txt?

Comment: No, el que quiero abrir se llama texto.txt. ¿He formulado mal el código? A ver si estoy llamando a fichero.txt

Comment: No no, solo me llamó la atención que el valor del argumento fichero fuera reemplazado por "texto.txt" en tu funcion.

Comment: Vale, perfecto. Sí. la verdad es que lo hubiera podido haber simplificado más en vez de dar tantas vueltas.

Comment: Quizá el directorio de trabajo (con que directorio se completaría un path relativo como texto.txt) **no** está en el directorio de tu script. Podrías agregar a la pregunta el resultado en tu codigo de este fragmento por favor? `import os print(os.getcwd())` Esto imprimira el directorio de trabajo en la consola.

Comment: También podrías el directorio de tu proyecto (si quieres puedes censurar lo que quieras de ambos directorios) por favor?

Comment: Ya estaría todo

Comment: Lo que sospechaba, el directorio de trabajo no es la carpeta del proyecto, en realidad está buscando el archivo cuyo path absoluto es `C:\Users\hp\texto.txt`. Conozco una solución que consiste en cambiar el directorio de trabajo. Pero quizá puedas configurar tu editor para que inicie el programa en el directorio de trabajo correcto. Que editor usas? Probaste con iniciar el programa usando el cmd y escribiendo  `python programa.py`?

Comment: Al empezar a leer tu respuesta ya he empezado a caer. Claro, error de novato. Muchas gracias y todo solucionado

Comment: De nada c: Por curiosidad, puedo saber que hiciste para solucionarlo? Cual fue el "error de novato"?

Comment: En mi editor , que es donde trabajo, he modificado el directorio, llevándolo directamente hacia donde están mis proyectos. Como tu mismo has indicado, el error consistía en que no se estaba buscando en el lugar que era, así que muchas gracias pues solo no hubiera caído tan fácilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacer esto:

en vez de poner simplemente `open(fichero, 'r')` haz una variable llamada **fichero** y dentro establece el **path** del fichero de la siguiente manera:

`fichero = r'D:\Tú\Programación\fichero.txt'`

`#luego pon`

`open(fichero, 'r')`

y sigue con tu código como lo tienes

Por su puesto el **path** (dirección del archivo dentro de tu pc)  de arriba es de **ejemplo** tu tienes q buscar el **path** del fichero q que quieres q está en la carpeta de origen de tu código y no olvides poner la **'r'** delante del **string** del **path** para q no te de error al leer el carácter \ en el **string**

Comment: Esta solución en mi opinion es poco flexible, pues te obliga a poner la ruta completa. Y que pasaría si quiero correr el programa en otro directorio? Tendré que editarlo a dicho programa?

Comment: Claro, yo más bien estoy buscando eso, correr el programa en otro directorio, donde se encuentren a propósito los archivos que necesito. Tal vez debería de especificarlo

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO:

> Lo que sospechaba, el directorio de trabajo no es la carpeta del proyecto, en realidad está buscando el archivo cuyo path absoluto es `C:\Users\hp\texto.txt`. Conozco una solución que consiste en cambiar el directorio de trabajo. Pero quizá puedas configurar tu editor para que inicie el programa en el directorio de trabajo correcto. Que editor usas? Probaste con iniciar el programa usando el cmd y escribiendo `python programa.py`? –
> Dante S.

Estaba utilizando Visual Studio Code. Aunque los dos archivos se encontraban en la misma carpeta, este editor llamaba a **texto.txt** desde `C:\Users\hp` no desde donde se encontraba **programa.py** que era `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (2)`

Iniciando el programa.py en el cmd todo funciona correctamente. (Lo que es lógico pues puse la ruta del directorio donde estaban ambos archivos, mediante el comando cd)

```
C:\Users\hp>cd desktop

C:\Users\hp\Desktop>cd Nueva carpeta (2)

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (2)>python programa.py
```